# Can't access docker at localhost:3000

Tags: docker, next.js

I'm following the following tutorial: https://medium.com/@khwsc1/a-simple-react-next-js-app-development-on-docker-6f0bd3f78c2c

When I try to access localhost:3000 however I get a "This site can’t be reached"

Not too sure what I'm doing wrong, when I run docker contqainer ls I definitely see the container running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `localhost:3333`.

Port `3333` is mapped on the host. Port `3000` is accessible inside the container.

Run command - `docker run -d -p 3333:3000 <your_username>/docker-nextjs:latest`